# Request Get keep response 401

Tags: python

I'm trying to GET requests but I keep getting an response 401

```
import requests
import json

payload = {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer fB5T3IaHjtUXQNb3IH0Lm4epcRHnkAK',
            'cache-control': 'no-cache'
            }
r = requests.get('https://api.vidoza.net/v1/upload/http/server/', params=payload)
print(r)
```

this is an example

```
curl -X GET \
  https://api.vidoza.net/v1/upload/http/server \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer fB5T3IaHjtUXQNb3IH0Lm4epcRHnkAK' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache'
```

What I'm getting

`<Response [401]>`

Comment: Why do you think your credentials are valid?

Comment: That's not my credentials, it's an example

Comment: Why do you think the credentials you are using are valid?

Comment: because I have my own credentials.....But what is your point?

Comment: If you don't have independent verification of the credentials, there isn't any point in investigating the code.